# How to copy from csv file by \copy in Postgres with URL in quotation?

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, copy

I have big csv file ( about 5gig) and wanna to import to PostgreSQl by \copy command in psql but I have problem with quotation and how to escape from that. 
So, this line is a an example of my csv file:

```
4644898,2111040746,DB975A18-760B-4FC2-A261-D7510B8AE15A,3630971,2016-08-20 02:22:26.983,0,0,0,0,"https://www.ulmart.ru/catalog/10184267?sort=0&viewType=0&rec=false&filters=8370:66683",
```

How I can do it with \copy command?

Comment: What problem do you have with quotation? Your CSV file line looks like it should work just fine.

Comment: There is a comma at the end of the line. Is that correct?